# Python How to get caller scrope

Tags: python, scope

```
def call(arg):
    return a+arg

def caller():
    a=1         
    call(2)

caller()
```

It returns: global name 'a' is not defined

Comment: you're not asking a clear question. This is how Python is supposed to work.

Comment: I need to access to caller scope from call function

Comment: that's not how python works.

Comment: pass `a` as parameter to call, e.g. `def call(arg, second_arg)`.

Comment: the whole point of having functions is not to be able to mess with the caller's context.

Comment: It was bad example. It looks more like
def cycle():
     for item in {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}:
          do('a')

def do(arg):
    if item.get(arg):
        pass

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `a` outside of your method definitions. In you code above the variable a is local to the method `caller`, by defining it outside of the method definitions you're giving it global scope.

The error you're getting is because python is looking for something with global scope, hence it says global name 'a' is not defined.

The code below works in python fiddle.

```
def call(arg):
    return a+arg

def caller():
    print call(2)

a=1        

caller()
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `a` is defined in function `caller`. Hence, accessing `a` in `caller` function works fine. In function `call` the variable `a` is not defined, hence Python raises the exception.

You can fix this by either of the two methods:

1. Pass `a` as argument along with `arg` in `call` function (preferred) Or
2. Define `a` as a global variable. (Not preferred) as global variables are considered a bad practice.

Try redefining function `call function` like

```
def call(a, arg):
    return a + arg
```

Answer (score 0):

It was bad example. It looks more like:

```
def cycle():
     for item in {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}:
          do('a')

def do(arg):
    if item.get(arg):
        pass
```

And I can't use classes because framework that I use doesn't support inheritance.